# Lambda expression select Count from virtual ICollection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda

i have an trouble with lambda expression i have some releated tables and i need to select some results with count and avarage functions here ise the example class

```
class Course{
public long id;
public string name;
public virtual ICollection<Chapter> chapters;
}

class Chapter{
public long id;
public virtual ICollection<Videos> videos;
public virtual ICollection<Files> files;
}
```

i need to select them into

```
select new{
videoCount = [number of video releated to course],
fileCount = [number of file releated to course],
}
```

how can i select with lambda expression like

```
var result = from c in Courses...
             i cant figured out here
             select new{
                          videoCount = [number of video releated to course],
                          fileCount = [number of file releated to course],
             };
```

thanks for your help.

> Blockquote

Comment: Could you show us your Videos and Files class too?

Answer (score 2):

You have an error in your code: after `public virtual ICollection<Chapter>` you don't have the property name. I assume it is called Chapters.
Same for Videos and Files properties.

Try this:

```
var result = courses.Select(c => new
{
    videoCount = c.chapters.Sum(chapter => chapter.Videos.Count()),
    fileCount = c.chapters.Sum(chapter => chapter.Files.Count())
});
```

You `Sum` the count of videos in each chapter, to get the total for the course.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var courses = new List<Course>();

courses.Select(x=> new { 
                       VideoCount = x.Chapters.Sum(v=>v.Videos.Count),
                       FilesCount = x.Chapters.Sum(v=>v.Files.Count)
                       });
```